# Magento MySQL database stock update

Tags: mysql, magento, phpmyadmin

I need some help updating all configurable products from

```
Manage Stock = no
and
Stock Availability = no
```

to

```
Manage Stock = yes
and
Stock Availability = yes
```

via the database...

the stock for the products I believe is in the table

```
cataloginventory_stock_item
```

however I can't see where the product type = configurable is defined in this table, which causes a bit of an issue as I can't see which to update...

Any thoughts would be very appreciated

Regards

Henry

Comment: Its going to be a foreign key to the products table.  I dont access to the schema right now, but it will probably link to another table (like producttypes) that will have an id that you need to query on.

Answer (score 1):

if you only update the configurable product quantity,best solution is `Go to admin>system>Import/Export>Dataflow - Profiles>Export Product Stocks`

Then select only Mapped Fields in Data Format and add these required fields (screen shot below) in Field Mapping section and save and continue,

[image]

Then go to Run Profile section in your left hand side and click on Run Profile button.

Connect FTP or download your csv `root/var/export/export_product_stocks.csv update product inventory or import Import/Export>Dataflow - Profiles>import Product Stocks`

upload your file and same run profile.

your all product's inventory will be updated.

Thanks......

Comment: I was having the same issue and your suggestion worked perfectly. Thank you.